SQL Server Hierarchical Sorting without IDs
Given an unsorted table:



Column1
Column2
Rank




elmo
Points
-2


grouch
cough
3


Points
Points
2


elmo
sneeze
-4


grouch
Points
4


elmo
yell
2


grouch
bite
1



I need to sort it based on:

'Points' values are prioritized the highest for each Column1 category, regardless of Rank
The whole table, and also each category, is sorted by Rank descending

So the final table will have Points / Points as the first row since that value is prioritized, therefore showing the overall Rank, and then Points values will be at the top of every Colunmn1 category, with Rank descending in value, like this:



Column1
Column2
Rank




$total
Points
2


grouch
Points
4


grouch
cough
3


grouch
bite
1


elmo
Points
-2


elmo
yell
2


elmo
sneeze
-4



Ideally, the code should work with tables with n columns (potentially more than just 2).
I'm trying to use a recursive CTE with a self-join to append a column for each iteration, but I'm very new to the concept and still an amateur with my SQL in general (in SSMS):
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT   column1 --Anchor
,column2
,rank
FROM MyTable
WHERE property0 = 'Points' --Since points in Column1 would be the highest level
UNION ALL
SELECT   t.column1 --Recursive
,t.column2
,t.points
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN cte
ON t.column2 = cte.column2 AND t.points = cte.points 
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY points DESC

But this is just giving me an maximum recursion limit error.

...how is this a hierarchy? This looks like a job for GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP instead...

Just use a CASE statement that converts $total to a value that is guaranteed to be greater than any actual value in the column and then sort by it

@puk82 What do you mean by "keep $total values at the top of each property"? SQL does not consider rows' positions relative to each other (a relation is an unordered set, after-all; consider that the ORDER BY clause can only be used in the last logical step of a query (i.e. ORDER BY cannot be used inside a CTE). I'm also unsure what you mean by "prioritized" here... what is  "priority"?

You should add an explicit "Total Rank" column then to make that clearer.

I note that the precise ordering/sorting/display of rows is a presentation layer concern, not a data-query-concern - so nontrivial sorting (e.g. sorting multiple rows as a group based on values on a single member of that group, etc) is often best done outside of SQL.

You can use ORDER BY and a CASE expression to set the priority of the rows:
SELECT Property0,
       Property1,
       net_sales
FROM   (
  SELECT Property0,
         Property1,
         net_sales,
         SUM(net_sales) OVER (PARTITION BY Property0) AS total_net_sales
  FROM   table_name
) t
ORDER BY
       CASE Property0 WHEN '$total' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
       total_net_sales DESC,
       Property0,
       CASE Property1 WHEN '$total' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
       net_sales DESC,
       Property1

or you can use ROLLUP (if you ignore the existing $total rows); which will generate rows for the totals with NULL values and then you can can use COALESCE to replace the NULLs with '$total'.
SELECT Property0,
       Property1,
       net_sales
FROM   (
  SELECT COALESCE(Property0, '$total') AS Property0,
         COALESCE(Property1, '$total') AS Property1,
         SUM(net_sales) AS net_sales,
         SUM(SUM(net_sales)) OVER (PARTITION BY Property0) AS total_net_sales,
         GROUPING_ID(Property0) AS gid0,
         GROUPING_ID(Property1) AS gid1
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  Property0 != '$total'
  AND    Property1 != '$total'
  GROUP BY ROLLUP(Property0, Property1)
) t
ORDER BY 
       gid0 DESC,
       total_net_sales DESC,
       Property0,
       gid1 DESC,
       net_sales DESC,
       Property1

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  Property0 VARCHAR(10),
  Property1 VARCHAR(10),
  net_sales INT
);

INSERT INTO table_name (Property0, Property1, net_sales) VALUES
  ('bar',    '$total', -200),
  ('foo',    'sauce',   300),
  ('$total', '$total',  200),
  ('bar',    'sup',    -400),
  ('foo',    '$total',  400),
  ('bar',    'bro',     200),
  ('foo',    'bacon',   100);

Both output:



PROPERTY0
PROPERTY1
NET_SALES




$total
$total
200


foo
$total
400


foo
sauce
300


foo
bacon
100


bar
$total
-200


bar
bro
200


bar
sup
-400



Oracle fiddle SQL Server fiddle

+1 - though I think you should explain how ROLLUP works here, because without it there won't be NULL in the Property0/Property1 columns and therefore the COALSECE wouldn't work.

@puk82 Updated to order by total net sales and then by net sales.
